# How to copy the last cell from the specific Column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to copy the last non empty cell from `Sheet1 Column A` and paste that cell into the last empty cell of the `Sheet2 Column D`.

But an error `The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.` is appearing. Any help will be appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName1 = "sheet1";
  const sheetName2 = "sheet2";


  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName1);
  const sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName2);

  const lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRow();
  const lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRow();

  sheet1.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow1).copyTo(sheet2.getRange("D" + (lastRow2 + 1)));

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

This line is trying to copy multiple rows to a range that has exceeded the dimensions of the target sheet, which is not allowed:

```
sheet1.getRange("A2:A" + lastRow1).copyTo(sheet2.getRange("D" + (lastRow2 + 1)));
```

Since you are trying to `copy the last non empty cell from Sheet1 Column A and paste that cell into the last empty cell of the Sheet2 Column D`, you can use this code to get that row instead:

```
const lastRow1 = sheet1.getLastRow();

var values = sheet2.getRange('D:D').getValues();
for (i = values.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (values[i][0] == "") break;
}
const lastRow2 = i;

sheet1.getRange("A" + lastRow1).copyTo(sheet2.getRange("D" + (lastRow2 + 1));
```

**Reference:**

[Class Range | copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer but the problem is still same https://ibb.co/rkL5xgs

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that your sheet2 does not have enough rows. Try adding enough rows in sheet2 based on how many rows you have in sheet1 before rerunning the script.

Comment: If you still encounter problems, please share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: Sheet2 has almost 10K rows but why this function is calculating the rows. Because both sheet will have different number of rows always

Comment: Sheet has private stuff that is difficult to share.

Comment: I edited my answer to make sure the last row of sheet 2 would not exceed the dimensions of the sheet.

Comment: I can share a link with you can grab it quickly

Comment: You all solutions are working for Temp sheet but all are failed in Original sheet. I do not know why.

Comment: I can only suggest that you log ``lastRow2`` when executing your code in the original sheet and make sure that the range exists in your target sheet.

Comment: I did here is the result https://ibb.co/7bzY5wQ

Comment: Can you try using ``sheet1.getRange(lastRow1,1)`` and ``sheet2.getRange(lastRow2,4)`` ? Does row 10018 actually exist in your sheet2?

Comment: script works fine but nothing happend